# Otsu Threshold in general

Tags: threshold

I want to know if I could use the Otsu Code for a Histogram which contains other data than greyValues? I have a set of mm which multiplied by 1000 to get int values and now I want to cut off the left part of the histogram with Otsu.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, why not? The algorithm doesn't know what the values mean, it just separates the values into two classes. You just have to make sure that the code you're using iterates over the full range of your int values.